# Application not loading data from hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jar, weblogic12c

Our application has 2 servers A and B and requests are managed by a load balancer.
Code is same inside two weblogic servers but 
when same page is loaded from one server it is getting displayed 
but same page loaded from second server its giving

**Error 500--Internal Server Error**

war file is same in both weblogic servers but when when I check logs I can see that some exception is observed.

org.hibernate.HibernateException: Problem while trying to load or access OracleTypes.CURSOR value
        at org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect.registerResultSetOutParameter(Oracle8iDialect.java:399)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1586)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
        at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:312)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1722)
        at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:175)

so I directly went through the dialect code in Oracle8iDialect.java inside the hibernate-3.2.7.ga jar file.

Hibernate uses the following code to load the ORACLE TYPES class.

```
public int registerResultSetOutParameter(CallableStatement statement, int col) throws SQLException {
                                //            register the type of the out param - an Oracle specific type
                                statement.registerOutParameter( col, getOracleCursorTypeSqlType() );
                                col++;
                                return col;
                }
```

So there is no code description inside the Oracle8iDialect.java that throws the above Exception “Problem while trying to load or access OracleTypes.CURSOR value” so I investigated that there is one more class with the same name Oracle8iDialect inside the z_easybeans-uberjar-hibernate-1.1.0-M3-JONAS.jar file. I think that the same class is conflicted between the two jar files by the class loader. So at runtime web logic pick up the oracle8idialect class file in z_easybeans-uberjar-hibernate-1.1.0-M3-JONAS.jar instead of correct class in hibernate-3.2.7.ga jar.

dialect code in Oracle8iDialect.java inside the z_easybeans-uberjar-hibernate-1.1.0-M3-JONAS.jar.

```
public int registerResultSetOutParameter(java.sql.CallableStatement statement,int col) throws SQLException {
if(oracletypes_cursor_value==0) {
                                                try {
                                                                Class types = ReflectHelper.classForName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes");
                                                                oracletypes_cursor_value = types.getField("CURSOR").getInt(types.newInstance());
                                                } catch (Exception se) {
                                                                throw new HibernateException("Problem while trying to load or access OracleTypes.CURSOR value",se);
                                                }
                                }
                                //            register the type of the out param - an Oracle specific type
                                statement.registerOutParameter(col, oracletypes_cursor_value);
                                col++;
                                return col;
                }
```

May be there is a different version of hibernate is used in this jar and that causes the conflict in second server

Any one Please provide us a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the Answer by help of a friend.

Changed dialect code in Oracle8iDialect.java inside the z_easybeans-uberjar-hibernate-1.1.0-M3-JONAS.jar.

```
public int registerResultSetOutParameter(java.sql.CallableStatement statement,int col) throws SQLException {
if(oracletypes_cursor_value==0) {
                                                try {
                                                                Class types = ReflectHelper.classForName("**oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes**");
                                                                oracletypes_cursor_value = types.getField("CURSOR").getInt(**null**);
                                                } catch (Exception se) {
                                                                throw new HibernateException("Problem while trying to load or access OracleTypes.CURSOR value",se);
                                                }
                                }
                                //            register the type of the out param - an Oracle specific type
                                statement.registerOutParameter(col, oracletypes_cursor_value);
                                col++;
                                return col;
                }
```

and compiled the particular dialect file and added the class file to z_easybeans-uberjar-hibernate-1.1.0-M3-JONAS.jar after deleting old class file

then made war and activated it from weblogic.

Then it worked normally.